# React Context changes causes app to freeze

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Context that stores an image link and if we're hovering on a link or not. It works like this: when a person hover on a link, we set the context to say that we're hovering on a link, we give it an image url, and the context updates a component with the image.

The problem is when you hover on the link, the app freezes completely for 1 second and only then shows the image. It works fine on FireFox, but doesn't work on Safari or Chrome.

**Context component**

```js
export const CursorContext = React.createContext();

export const CursorProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [image, rawSetImage] = React.useState(null);

  const contextValue = React.useMemo(() => {
    function setImage(newValue) {
      rawSetImage(newValue);
    }

    return {
      image,
      setImage,
    };
  }, [image, rawSetImage]);

  return <CursorContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</CursorContext.Provider>;
};
```

**Link hover component**

```js
const PhotoLink = ({ data }) => {
  const { setImage } = useContext(CursorContext);
  const [hovering, setHovering] = useState(false);

  useMemo(() => {
    if (hovering)
      setImage({
        hovering: true,
        url: data.headshot.url,
      });
    else
      setImage({
        hovering: false,
        url: data.headshot.url,
      });
  }, [hovering]);

  return (
    <a onMouseEnter={() => setHovering(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHovering(false)}>
      Hover me to see photo
    </a>
  );
};
```

**Image component**

```js
const CursorImage = () => {
  const { image } = React.useContext(CursorContext);

  if (!image) return null;

  return (
    <StyledImage
      src={image.url}
      alt={image.alt}
      style={{ opacity: image.hovering ? 1 : 0 }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Were you supposed to use `useEffect` instead of `useMemo` in your Link hover component

Comment: But he said it works on Firefox, if the code was wrong shouldn't it not work at all? The fact that he talks about freezing makes me think that some component is re-rendering when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I read up on preventing re-renderings here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156

following the 3rd option example

```
function Button() {
  let appContextValue = useContext(AppContext);
  let theme = appContextValue.theme; // Your "selector"

  return useMemo(() => {
    // The rest of your rendering logic
    return <ExpensiveTree className={theme} />;
  }, [theme])
}
```

could you try something like the following:

**Link Hover Component**

```
const PhotoLink = ({ data }) => {
const {setImage} = useContext(CursorContext)
let image = setImage.data
```